# How do I right align the text in a wx.ComboBox?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a combobox in wxpython but I cant figure out how to align the text it contains to the right?

I have tried to use `wx.ComboBox(self, choices=["1","2","3"], style=wx.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_RIGHT)` but that didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget probably doesn't support text alignment. If you want complete control over how it displays its contents, then you should probably switch to a custom drawn control, such as ComboCtrl.

Comment: I can confirm that at least under MSW the native widget indeed doesn't support specifying the alignment.

Comment: If thats the case, then I guess changing the default alignment may not be a good idea as it will not look natural.